# Adjusting button using CSS

Tags: html, css

In the below image, how can I adjust the close button such that it is placed at the top right corner of the light box?

[image]

I have the following code

```
<div id="lightbox_fg">
    <h2 id="search_result_display"><button id="close" onClick="closeLightBox()" style="float:right; top:0px; position:relative;">&times;</button></h2>
    <button id="close" onClick="closeLightBox()" style="float:right;">&times;</button>
    <form name="search_form" id="search_form" onSubmit="return false;">
    <input name="searchedit" id="searchedit" type="text" size="30" maxlength="100" value="">
    In:
    <select name="filter1" id="filter1">
      <option value="users">Users</option>
      <option value="forum">Forums</option>
    </select>
    <button id="searchBtn" onClick="searchMyWebsiteFG()">Search</button>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="search_output" style="width:800px; height:385px; border:#000 1px solid; overflow:scroll;"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

I'm talking about the button with id="close". What should I change in the style attribute?

Comment: Position it absolutely. `position: absolute; top:10px; right:10px;` - You'll probably need to play around with the top and right values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to move all your styles into an external style sheet rather then having them inline.
My advice would be to position the close button element absolutely and its parent relatively. then set something like

```
    #close{
        position:absolute;
        top:-5px;
        right: -5px;
    }
```

there is a good article here on css [positioning](http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101)
and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started) is a good beginners guide to css

Comment: It worked!! Can you tell me how I can change the size of &times;

Comment: for the text, something like font-size:20px; for the dimensions of the buttons just height : [some height]px etc